# Prevent body from scrolling when scrolling on fixed div

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I create a fixed div with `overflow: scroll` in such a way that `body` won't scroll when hovering over the div and scrolling? Sort of like the fixed chat boxes at the bottom of the window on facebook.com.

I've tried using javascript to capture and stop the `scroll`, `wheel` and `touchmove` events from bubbeling up with `stopPropagation()`, but it doesn't seem to work.

I've simplified the problem as much as I can here: https://jsfiddle.net/m9uamaza/

The goal is to scroll up and down in the fixed "bar" div without the "foo" body moving. If the "bar" div is scrolled all the way to the bottom, and I keep scrolling, I don't want the body to start scrolling. The body should still be scrollable when the mouse is not over the fixed div.

Answer (score 1):

I have Updated your answer here is the link

https://jsfiddle.net/m9uamaza/3/

I have modified in following code

```
inner.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
if(e.wheelDelta < 0) {
  if((this.scrollHeight-this.scrollTop-200)<=0){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
     }
    else
    if(this.scrollTop==0){
       e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

Also providing Demo here, if you want like that

```js
var inner = document.getElementById('inner'); 
var outer = document.getElementById('outer'); 

inner.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}, false);

inner.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
if(e.wheelDelta < 0) {
  if((this.scrollHeight-this.scrollTop-200)<=0){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
     }
    else
    if(this.scrollTop==0){
       e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);

inner.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

```css
.fixed { 
  position: fixed; 
  top: 100px; 
  left: 100px; 
  background-color: #eef; 
  height: 200px; 
  width: 200px; 
  overflow-y: scroll; 
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="outer"> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
    <p>foo</p> 
  <div class="fixed" id="inner"> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p> 
      <p>bar</p>  
    </div> 
  </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but this does not seem to solve the problem. If I scroll the "foo" body about halfway down, and then hover the mouse over the fixed "bar" div and scroll up, the "foo" body will scroll back up. Another quirk is if the bar div is scrolled all the way to the bottom, the user will not be able to scroll up again. I might not have expressed my problem clear enough. I'll try to edit my question and explain my problem better.

Comment: This time check it is working or not I have updated again. Hope you want like that